# Mockito, verify a function is invoked 0 time(s)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to write my test case. I have a simple class which contains a function `countPerson(boolean)` which I am interested to test:

```
public class School {
    //School is a singleton class.

    public void countPerson(boolean includeTeacher) {
        if (includeTeacher) {
            countIncludeTeacher();
            return;
        }
        countOnlyStudents();
    }

    public void countIncludeTeacher() {...}
    public void countOnlyStudents() {...}
}
```

In my unit test, I want to test the `countPerson(boolean)` method:

```
@Test 
public void testCountPerson() {    
    School mSchool = School.getInstance();
    School spySchool = Mockito.spy(mSchool);
    spySchool.countPerson(true);

    //Verify the function countIncludeTeacher is invoked once
    verify(spySchool).countIncludeTeacher();
    //Until here things are working well.

    spySchool.countPerson(false);
    //ERROR HERE when I try to verify the function has 0 times invoke
    verify(spySchool, times(0)).countIncludeTeacher();      
}
```

I have the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
>       school.countIncludeTeacher();
>       Never wanted here: (SchoolTest.java 20)

Why does the 0 times verify not work?

Comment: Because it has been called, in the first part of the test. You even have verified it before. Write 2 tests instead of one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that each `verify` call is made on the same `spySchool` instance. Let me explain:

```
@Test 
public void testCountPerson() {    
    School mSchool = School.getInstance();
    School spySchool = Mockito.spy(mSchool); // a spy is created here, Mockito is listening in.
    spySchool.countPerson(true); // real method is invoked
    verify(spySchool).countIncludeTeacher(); // our spy identified that countIncludeTeacher was called

    spySchool.countPerson(false); // real method is invoked
    verify(spySchool, times(0)).countIncludeTeacher(); // our spy still identified that countIncludeTeacher was called, before it was called before
}
```

The thing is that in the latest `verify`, it fails because the `countIncludeTeacher` method was called on the spy before and that called was not deregistered.

You can do it using [`verifyNoMoreInteractions`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.16/org/mockito/Mockito.html#finding_redundant_invocations), which verifies that the object had no more interactions. You could also [reset](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.16/org/mockito/Mockito.html#resetting_mocks) the object.

But note that this is really not recommended, quoting Mockito Javadoc:

> A word of **warning**: Some users who did a lot of classic, expect-run-verify mocking tend to use `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` very often, even in every test method. `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` is not recommended to use in every test method. `verifyNoMoreInteractions()` is a handy assertion from the interaction testing toolkit. Use it only when it's relevant. Abusing it leads to overspecified, less maintainable tests. You can find further reading here.

And

> Smart Mockito users hardly use this feature because they know it could be a sign of poor tests. Normally, you don't need to reset your mocks, just create new mocks for each test method.
>
> Instead of `reset()` please consider writing simple, small and focused test methods over lengthy, over-specified tests. **First potential code smell is `reset()` in the middle of the test method**. This probably means you're testing too much. Follow the whisper of your test methods: "Please keep us small & focused on single behavior".

I would definitely suggest that you split this test in two: one for the `true` case and one for the `false` case.

Comment: Mockito also has `never()` as a verification mode.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you actually DO invoke `countIncludeTeacher()` when you run `spySchool.countPerson(true)` in your test.
This branches out to your other function, recoding as an invocation on the spy object.

In your current setup, you would either have to verify it was called only once, or reset your spy object instance before running the second test.

Comment: I agree with @kasoban, it looks like you are doing too much in this test.  If you split it into two tests, then your verify is simpler and you won't need to reset anything.